# React Bootstrap Accordion on table

Tags: reactjs, accordion

Hi is anyone know how to implement accordion on react table? im trying to hide my entire table upon clicking a title ( tag). thank you

```
<div class="Asalertpf1 block" > 

                    <FormLabel className="btn-success d-flex justify-content-center m-0">
                        <h6 >PF1 AS Alert</h6>
                    </FormLabel>

                    <div >
                    <Table striped hover responsive >
                    <thead className="theadAS text-white thAS" >
                        <tr className="text-center" >
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Job Name</th>
                        <th>Result</th>
                        <th>Alarm Switch</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                        </Table>
                    </div>
                  <div>

                  <p class="text-center font-weight-bold ">
                      Latest Update Time: 
                          {new Date().toDateString()}&nbsp;
                          {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
                        </p>

                  </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using reactstrap?

Comment: You can provide your `bootstrap table code` so that we can show how can you do that and this documentation will help you how to implement `accordion` easily: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Comment: hi i edited the codeblock now, im trying to do it that when i clicked the entire formlabel, it will hide/show the entire table thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you maintain a state say `open` and have an onClick on the title and toggle the state `open`

[Working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-simple-table-sp5y3?file=/index.js)

The example uses a simple div without styles but you get the idea.

**Example snippet:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: makeData(),
      open: true
    };
  }
  toggleAccordian = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, open: !prev.open }));
  };
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{ background: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={this.toggleAccordian}
        >
          toggle table
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            margin: "20px",
            display: this.state.open ? "block" : "none"
          }}
        >
          <ReactTable
            data={data}
            columns={[
              {
                Header: "First Name",
                accessor: "firstName",
                className: "sticky",
                headerClassName: "sticky"
              },
    ......
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, if you are using any library you can make use of [ready-made accordions](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/)